# How do I change language on Firefox 60.0.2 (64 bit)?

Tags: kubuntu, firefox

Running: Kubuntu 18.04 (os set to Japanese today)

However Firefox is still set to English, I went through the options on Firefox; there is an option to change preferred languages for viewing pages but how do I set the language for the UI?

Comment: I think this question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate since the linked question doesn’t provide the answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Firefox interface in other languages with language packs

-Go to https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-interface-other-languages-language-pack to d download you language and install it.

Then change the language.

-In the address bar type about:config (accept the risk)

-Type intl.locale.requested in the Search field.

-Double-click the intl.locale.requested preference.

-Enter the code of the language you want to use as the string value or leave it blank to use the language of your system.

-Click the Firefox menu three horizontal bars button then exit.

When you start Firefox again, you will see the interface in the new specified language.

Comment: Worth noting that ehrnd21’s link provides official instructions from Mozilla for changing the language of the Firefox UI, a direct link to the language packs is at https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/language-tools/, the “three horizontal bars button” is more properly called the “hamburger menu button”, and Firefox can be directly restarted by using Ctrl+Shift+J to open the Browser Console followed by Ctrl+Alt+R while the Browser Console is open.